# What does it mean by chrome v8 engine embeded nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to MEAN, when i am learning node.js they say nodejs is embeded with chrome v8 engine, does nodejs work on specific browser. can brief what is nodejs embeded on chrome v8 engine not on other browser engines

Answer (score 0):

node.js is a Javascript execution environment that stands by itself.  It has nothing to do with a browser.  You can run Javascript programs with just node.js.

To parse and execute Javascript, node.js has the V8 Javascript engine (the same engine used by Chrome) embedded in it.  This just allows it to run and execute Javascript.  It does not make it a browser in any way.

In addition to the V8 Javascript execution engine, node.js also comes with a large set of built-in libraries for doing all sorts of things from socket communication to file I/O, allowing one to write all sorts of applications in node.js, including even server processes.

> does nodejs work on specific browser

If you build a server process in node.js, you can use any browser to talk to that server, either via regular HTTP page requests, form posts, Ajax calls or webSocket connections.

> what is nodejs embeded on chrome v8 engine not on other browser engines

nodejs needs only one Javascript execution engine.  V8 is open source and a very good engine so that's what the developers of nodejs decided to use.  Which Javascript engine is used has nothing to do with any browser or any interoperability with any browser.  node.js stands on it's own.  Any browser can talk to it using standards defined for http or webSocket.

Comment: @Som - Why did you remove the checkmark as the accepted answer?  Is there something in your question that you think my answer is missing?

Answer (score -1):

node.js is using v8 as core. Node has in itself. there's no browser limitation for working node.js because node.js running on server.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for waking me up. that's wrong im correcting it